# How do you import user profiles without using User Profile Synchronization Services

Tags: 2010, user-profile, synchronisation

I was told by a SharePoint MVP, that it was possible to run a SharePoint 2010 environment without using the "User Profile Synchronization Service" (which we are not able to use in our environment).

My question is, how would you go about importing user profiles without this service?

Comment: I would ask that MVP. Sometime they have cool or proven ideas that don't make it to blogs or article.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on why you cannot use user profiles? Is this a license issue or is it because you do not have an AD or similar to synchronize up against? There are other ways...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can run SharePoint (no matter 2007 or 2010) w/o UPS Service. In that case you will have "simplified" profiles containing only basic params: login name, name, email... No any additional configuration steps required to work that way. Btw, SharePoint Foundation Server uses this model by default (there are no UPS Service at all)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you can´t use the UPS in your SharePoint 2010 environment, but If you want to synch userprofiles that you have within for example your own developed userprofiles application that is hosted within a SQL database (there is support for other LOB systems aswell like Oracle) you can use Business Connectivity Service Application and create an external content type with SharePoint Designer 2010.

You can read more about it here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx

Regards
Johan